# Using Delphi with Indy to make a GET with a SSL url

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I am using XE8.
My openssl dlls are in 1.0.2.13 version.

I have the next site with the documentation  to get some currency exchange values:
https://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/#documentacao

I am trying the next code, but I get an error:

```
'Error connecting with SSL.'#$D#$A'error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'
```

if I put the next line into browser "http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores" it returns the correct values.

How could I fix it?

My code:

```
const ss='http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores';
    var
      s: string;
      lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
      HandlerSock:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    begin
      lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
      try
        HandlerSock:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
        HandlerSock.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
        HandlerSock.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1];
        lHTTP.IOHandler := HandlerSock;
        lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
        s := lHTTP.Get(ss);
        ShowMessage(s);
      finally
        lHTTP.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

If I use the next code, it works, but It doesn't uses Indy. I´d like pure Indy code.

```
const ss='https://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores';
var
  Resp, Req: TStringStream;
  recieveID: Integer;
  Rio: THTTPRIO;
  s, tv: string;
begin
  Rio := THTTPRIO.Create(Nil);
  Rio.HTTPWebNode.URL :=ss;
  Rio.HTTPWebNode.CheckContentType; 
  Rio.HTTPWebNode.Agent :='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
  Rio.Port := '443';
  Result := '';
  Resp := TStringStream.Create('');
  Req := nil;
  try
    Req := TStringStream.Create(s, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      recieveID := Rio.HTTPWebNode.Send(Req); // Request
      Rio.HTTPWebNode.Receive(recieveID, Resp, false); // Response
      Resp.Position := 0;
      Result:=Resp.DataString;
    except
      on e:exception do begin
        Result := '';
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if Assigned(Req) then
      Req.Free;
    Resp.Free;
    Rio.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your Indy code that should be causing a TLS handshake failure. But I won't be able to test it until Monday. However, do note that your Delphi version and OpenSSL DLLs are not the latest (Tokyo 10.2 and 1.0.2.15, respectively). Try updating to the [latest Indy snapshot](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx), and the [latest OpenSSL DLLs](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/), and see if it helps..

Comment: Remy, I just did a test with Delphi Berlin Edition in other PC. I get the same error.

Comment: I'll report back when I have a chance to try it myself in a couple of days

Comment: I have news. With XE8,  I download the latest indy snapshot. I make settings of the search path of my project to the new Indy Folder(Protocols,System and Core). I put the latest OpenSSL DLLs into my project folder  and I recompiled. All works well. With Berlin, I just put the latest OpenSSL DLLs into my project folder and recompiled. It worked as well. Thank you Remy.

Comment: Concerning to SSL, you can tell me which indy units are affected from XE8 to Berlin. If I know, i will copy only that units to  my project folder. I want avoid reinstall indy.